# Problems launching many nodes on OSX

Tags: roscpp, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently did a fresh install of ROS-jade on OSX El Capitan and for the most part everything is working well. However, I have noticed that when launching large launch files (e.g., 100 nodes), there seems to be problems accessing the ROS master (registering pub/sub, reading params, etc).

In an effort to test things, I wrote a simple test node:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>

void onFloatSub(const std_msgs::Float64::ConstPtr& msg)
{

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_node");

  ros::NodeHandle pnh("~");

  ros::Subscriber sub = pnh.subscribe<std_msgs::Float64>("float_sub", 1, &onFloatSub);
  ros::Publisher pub = pnh.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("float_pub", 1);

  ros::Rate r(10.0);
  while(ros::ok()) {

    std::string test_param_value;
    if(!pnh.getParam("test_param", test_param_value)) {
      ROS_ERROR("Unable to read local 'test_param'");
    }

    if(test_param_value != std::string("test_param_value_set"))
      ROS_ERROR("Incorrect test_param_value!");

    ros::spinOnce();

    r.sleep();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And ran 100 versions of it in a launch file

```
<node pkg="test_many_node" type="test_many_node" name="test_node_1" output="screen">
    <param name="test_param" value="test_param_value_set"/>
</node>
```

(with nodes 1 through 100).

Some nodes seem to run ok, but then I see errors like these (which are similar to what I saw in more complicated, real-world examples):

```
...
process[test_node_53-54]: started with pid [25907]
process[test_node_54-55]: started with pid [25908]
process[test_node_55-56]: started with pid [25909]
process[test_node_56-57]: started with pid [25910]
[ERROR] ros.test_many_node> Unable to read local 'test_param'
[ERROR] ros.test_many_node> Incorrect test_param_value!
[ERROR] ros.test_many_node> Unable to read local 'test_param'
[ERROR] ros.test_many_node> Incorrect test_param_value!
[ERROR] ros.roscpp> [registerService] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
...
```

I don't *think* that I have experienced this problem before upgrading to El Capitan - has anyone else seen similar problems or have thoughts on things to try? I did a quick check on a Ubuntu machine (in a virtualized Docker image) and everything worked fine...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240430/problems-launching-many-nodes-on-osx/) by [jonfink](https://answers.ros.org/users/25176/jonfink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-07-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, almost 24 hours later and I have a solution (but not quite a full explanation).

It comes down to "something" that changed in the OSX build of python 2.7 on El Capitan with respect to handling sockets. The ROS `ThreadingXMLRPCServer` python class inherits from the `SimpleXMLRPCServer` class which inherits the `SocketServer.TCPServer`class. The TCPServer class sets a default parameter `request_queue_size=5` which controls how big it will allow the incoming connection queue to become (that is, the queue of *new* connections - this value gets passed down to the python [`socket.listen()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen))

I don't know what changed in OSX 10.11, maybe the rate at which the kernel allows connections or maybe how `socket.listen()` is implemented. Either way, I found any easy fix to be changing the ROS `ThreadingXMLRPCServer` class:

```
class ThreadingXMLRPCServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    """
    Adds ThreadingMixin to SimpleXMLRPCServer to support multiple concurrent
    requests via threading. Also makes logging toggleable.
    """
    def __init__(self, addr, log_requests=1):
        """
        Overrides SimpleXMLRPCServer to set option to allow_reuse_address.
        """
        # allow_reuse_address defaults to False in Python 2.4.  We set it
        # to True to allow quick restart on the same port.  This is equivalent
        # to calling setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        self.request_queue_size = 128
...
```

To increase the `request_queue_size` variable. I'll make an issue/pull-request to the `ros_comm` repos on github.

---

Originally posted by [jonfink](https://answers.ros.org/users/25176/jonfink/) with karma: 21 on 2016-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1